# SQL String function to find each iteration of a specified value and return

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to parse a particular field and return me just a portion of the string.

Example:

My varchar field contains the following string.

```
CN=PHLSERVER01,OU=Servers,OU=PHL,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office
CN=NYCSFAX01,OU=Servers,OU=NYC,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office 
CN=KONGRDATA01,OU=ServersToDelete,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office 
CN=LAXSERVER01,OU=Servers,OU=LAX,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office
```

I just want to query and return the CN name (common name). So in this example I'd want to see:

```
PHLSERVER01,NYCSFAX01,KONGRDATA01,LAXSERVER01
```

Comment: if you are using SQL Server 2016 you could use STRING_SPLIT see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx

Comment: @ironstone13 Unfortunately not on SQL 2016 but SQL 2008 R2

Comment: In an earlier version of SQL Server, you can write a function to emulate STRING_SPLIT that splits a string to a table, for exmple see this post https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html

Comment: Returned as 1 delimited string or records'

Comment: Is this example really just one record, or is that 4 rows of data?

Comment: That is one record

Comment: Seems easier to just query AD directly through a linked server then

Comment: I'm not sure how to query AD directly? I did not know that information was stored in a database somewhere. Would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a Split/Parse Function (many options available)

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeString varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'CN=PHLSERVER01,OU=Servers,OU=PHL,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office CN=NYCSFAX01,OU=Servers,OU=NYC,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office CN=KONGRDATA01,OU=ServersToDelete,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office CN=LAXSERVER01,OU=Servers,OU=LAX,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office')


Select A.ID
      ,CN = B.RetVal
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetVal=Replace(RetVal,'CN=','')
                 From  (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ replace((Select Replace(A.SomeString,' ',',') as [*] For XML Path('')),',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) C
                   Where RetVal Like '%CN=%'
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  CN
1   PHLSERVER01
1   NYCSFAX01
1   KONGRDATA01
1   LAXSERVER01
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer however is there a way to do it without adding a function to the database?

Comment: @StevenCellini Sure one moment

Comment: @StevenCellini Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL Server 2016 you could use [STRING_SPLIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) to split the value by comma char, and then select only those records that start with CN using [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

In an earlier version of SQL Server, you can write a function to emulate STRING_SPLIT that splits a string to a table, for exmple see this post https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution would be to create a table valued function that that accepts a string as input and returns a table of your key value pairs. Then simply use a string index function.

```
DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Data='CN=PHLSERVER01,OU=Servers,OU=PHL,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office CN=NYCSFAX01,OU=Servers,OU=NYC,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office CN=KONGRDATA01,OU=ServersToDelete,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office CN=LAXSERVER01,OU=Servers,OU=LAX,OU=Offices,DC=test,DC=test2,DC=office'

SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunctionToConvertDelimitedStringToTable(@Data,',')
WHERE
CHARINDEX('CN',Key)>0
```